# Why is the type signature of getEvent what it is?

Tags: haskell, ncurses, type-signature

The type signature for `getEvent` from the [`UI.NCurses`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ncurses-0.2.16/docs/UI-NCurses.html) library has the type signature

```
Window -> Maybe Integer -> Curses (Maybe Event)
```

However having used this function a bunch I am still not quite sure what the `Window` is used for.  The documentation says that it

> Get[s] the next Event from a given window.

But that doesn't really enlighten me very much (and reading the source code is similarly unenlightening for me). It would seem to me that if an event like a keypress happens it doesn't happen within a window.  And experimentation supports this hypothesis, I seem to pick up the same events regardless of what window I pass. If I have several windows open what difference does it make if I pass one or the other?

And if it does in fact use the window why is the type signature not the more natural

```
Maybe Integer -> Update (Maybe Event)
```

Comment: You say, "I seem to pick up the same events regardless of what window I pass". I guess by this you mean that if you replace `getEvent foo` everywhere in your program with `getEvent bar`, nothing changes. But what if you change only some occurrences of `getEvent foo` to `getEvent bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The `getEvent` function *needs* a window

The Haskell NCurses library is written on top of the GNU ncurses library, a C library.
Since the GNU ncurses library has separate input queues for each window, the `getEvent` function will need to know which window to get the input from when it makes calls to the appropriate GNU ncurses routines. The need for windows to have separate input queues is probably more apparent when input is not processed as soon as it is received.

### `Update` monad vs. `Window` argument? Arbitrary

The `UI.NCurses` package contains an unexported function

```
withWindow :: (Window -> IO a) -> Update a
```

that, as its type suggests, can be used to easily convert a function that takes a `Window` as input to one that returns its result wrapped in the `Update` monad.
It seems like the people who developed the Haskell NCurses library just thought that `getEvent` would work better in most cases taking a `Window` as an argument instead of using the `Update` monad.

Answer (score 2):

In general, Haskell wants all of a function's "dependencies" to be passed in as arguments. Within the body of `getEvent` it is using the passed in `win` argument a few times.

The OO analogy would be `window.getEvent(timeout)`. In FP though, aside from the ordering of the parameters to a function, there's nothing special about the first argument.

As to what would happen if you passed a different window, the docs say:

> Get the next 'Event' from a given window.

So, presumably, you're getting events scoped to the particular window that was passed as an argument. To analogize with OO further, that's the difference between:

```
myMainWindow.getEvent(100)
popupWindow.getEvent(250)
```

That is to say, different *instances* of `window`.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with OO so I think a little bit of this goes over my head.  If it is a scoping issue isn't the `Maybe Integer -> Update (Maybe Event)` more appropriate?  I'm really wondering why the actions taken with the window are not appropriate for a `Update` monad.

Comment: Ah, okay I understand now. As @1000000000 mentioned, I don't think one is intrinsically better than the other -- it's an API design decision. I tend to opt for "flatter" designs. If I can get away with using a record of functions, I'll do that.

I think of `Reader`-based solutions as being for global config. As an example, when starting a web app, the database connection pool goes into a `ReaderT` as part of an `App` monad transformer stack.